# specify staticfiles to be loaded in every django template?

Tags: django, templates, include

Is there a way to do `{% load staticfiles %}` automatically in every template file?
Would it significantly affect performance?

If it's a bad practice, I wonder if the following use-case is ok.
I'm **include**ing a file in a loop, and loading staticfiles,

```
{% for a in a_list %}
  {% include "a.html" %}
{% endfor %}
```

a.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
use {% static "a.html" %}
```

Comment: You need to load staticfiles in each template, if your html in that template makes use of them. That is recommended by django. No need to use for loop. just put load staticfiles.

Comment: I'm using static filter that's included repeatedly. and wondering if that's ok-practice

Comment: that is not a filter, static is a tag. You are fine with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the `static` tag automatically loaded into the set of default tag available in a template using the [`add_to_builtins`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/base.py#L1320) method from `template.base`:

```
from django.template.base import add_to_builtins
add_to_buildins('django.templatetag.static')
```

This code would probably be best placed in your `settings.py` file, or anywhere else that gets imported automatically.

Comment: As a quick note, this will be possible through the `Engine` settings as of Django 1.9 (and possibly deprecated, not sure about that). See the [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17085) and a bit of [documentation](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/templates/api.html). Maybe the answer could be updated, then I will remove the comment.